# How to exclude irrelevant objects from classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification

what is the best way in your experience to exclude irrelevant objects from NN classifier ?

let's say I classify among different shapes of bottles (beer, wine, soda..). I want to have a class "other" where would fall any picture not relevant (cat, car, house, whatever - anything that is not a bottle).

I can obviously not be exhaustive in the training of the class "other".

Doesn't matter to me if the solution would be inside the network or preprocessed with any classifier (NN or not) before.

What is the best solution you have found for this issue in your experience?

Thanks in advance

K.

Comment: If your task is to classify beverages - wine, soda, beer, water etc. Then you will have a probability for each of those outputs. If the highest probability is _not_ higher than some value, you should return 'other'. I don't think it is necessary to add an output label 'other'.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. It can happen that I have a very high probability for something completely not related to the targeted objects :/ And this kind of threshold  would decrease the performances of my network for difficult cases where he is less sure but still answers correctly.

Comment: There is no best solution for this, it is a open research problem.

Comment: yes I know it is open research ^_^  that is why I am asking for pragmatic heuristic people have experienced positively.

Comment: @Kalanit SO is not a site to discuss open research problems, it is a coding site, maybe another SE site like stats is more appropriate.